# Outlook Office 365 IMAP Folder not syncing with server

Tags: email, outlook

I have tried moving a folder from one mail address to another.

Both mail addresses are accessed using IMAP through 1and1.

I am running Office 365 version 15.0.4787.1002

I have added both account to outlook (info@domain1.uk and info@domain2.uk)

Now I have then dragged across the folder structrue from info@domain1.uk to info@domain2.uk.

This simply copied across the folder structure and none of the emails. So I then manually dragged all email files across to each relevent folder as well.

Now, locally in my outlook all the emails are in the correct place. However, to test i logged into the 1and1 webmail portal.

Now the emails have been removed from the first account but do not appear in the second account?

Am I missing something here to tell the account to sync the newly created folder?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Seeing this on some clients , some where i fond a fix ,
basically on 1and1 you have a send items and sent messages folders and outlook just picks one of them ...
what i did was logon to 1and1 web mail pick sent message and create a sub folder "thisone" then in outlook re-sync see it shows up. if not your syncing the sent item folder, if it does its the sent messages folder ,  on 1and1 move all emails to the right folder . witch will the sync to outlook 
hope this helps
g...